# AWS DMS Task doesn't apply inserts, updates, and deletes on Elasticache Redis cluster target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster, dms

I have a full load and CDC DMS task configured to replicate data in Aurora MySQL cluster to Elasticache Redis cluster. For some reason I see that change come to task but are not applied to Redis cluster.

I tried to apply different task settings. Upgraded Redis engine version to 7.0.4.

Here's a current task settings:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "LogComponents": [
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TRANSFORMATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "IO"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_LOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "PERFORMANCE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SORTER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "REST_SERVER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_APPLY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TASK_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TABLES_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "METADATA_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_FACTORY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMON"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "ADDONS"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMUNICATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_TRANSFER"
            }
        ],
        "CloudWatchLogGroup": "dms-tasks-dsp-engine-prod-replication-instance",
        "CloudWatchLogStream": "dms-task-VZ6ESTKIA3V6CAZAQRGK2Q76EAV4OASWIKR5JJY"
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": true,
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "EventErrorPolicy": "IGNORE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "RecoverableErrorCount": 0,
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 50,
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 50,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE"
    },
    "TTSettings": {
        "TTS3Settings": null,
        "TTRecordSettings": null,
        "EnableTT": false
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "CommitRate": 10000,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE"
    },
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 100,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 1,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 1,
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 0,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "LobMaxSize": 32,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "FullLobMode": false,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0
    },
    "BeforeImageSettings": {
        "EnableBeforeImage": false,
        "ColumnFilter": "pk-only",
        "FieldName": ""
    },
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "StatusTableEnabled": true,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": true,
        "ControlSchema": "",
        "FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false
    },
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false,
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "StatementCacheSize": 50,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null
}
```

[image]

Redis engine version is 7.0.4

Is there any option that's actually controls whether changes should be applied?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that in my case it was because of source filters. They don't work the way I expected. Not only records are filtered in full load stage, but updates in cdc stage are filtered too. That's why there's Updates and Applied updates columns.